# Fragment having a GridView to show images from url path

Tags: java, javascript, android, gridview, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a gridview that shows images and So it shows the gridview but no images, if clicked it boxes the gridview pops out the link. i got no idea why my images is missing on the gridview...

heres my fragment class

```
public class FragmentD extends Fragment {
    public FragmentD(){}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_d, container, false);

    try {
        EditText main_searchField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_search_d);
        String main_search = main_searchField.getText().toString();

        Spinner main_categoryField = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_d);
        String category = main_categoryField.getSelectedItem().toString();

        GridView main_gridviewField = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView_main);
        main_gridviewField.setAdapter(new MyGridViewAdapter(getActivity()));


        main_gridviewField.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), MyGridViewConfig.getResim_list().
                        get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        if(main_gridviewField.isActivated()){
            ImageView sad_face = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView_main_sadface);
            sad_face.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TextView nosuchdata = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView_main_nodatafound);
            nosuchdata.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "EPIC FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //new search_mainActivity(getActivity()).execute(main_search, category);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

heres my adapter

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private Context context;

public MyGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;

    MyGridViewConfig.addImageUrls();
}


public int getCount() {
    return MyGridViewConfig.getResim_list().size();

}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return MyGridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position);
}


public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        imageView=new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    }else{
        imageView=(ImageView)convertView;

    }

    imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(MyGridViewConfig.
            getResim_list().get(position)));
    return imageView;
}

private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url)

{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

heres my config java

```
public class MyGridViewConfig {

private static ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();

public static ArrayList<String> getResim_list() {
    return resim_list;

}

public static void setResim_list(ArrayList<String> resim_list) {
    MyGridViewConfig.resim_list = resim_list;
}
public static void addImageUrls(){
    //  Here you have to specify your image url path

    resim_list.add("http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg");
    resim_list.add("http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg");
    resim_list.add("http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg");
    resim_list.add("http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg");
    resim_list.add("http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg");
    resim_list.add("http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't download the images on your main UI thread, so do it in an AsyncTask. Create this class:

```
class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable > {
    public LoadImageTask(ImageView iv)
    {
        imageView = iv;
    }
    ImageView imageView;
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(urls[0]).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) connection.getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
        if(drawable != null)
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

Then change your getView() function to use the AsyncTask instead of LoadImageFromURL:

```
// imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(MyGridViewConfig.
//        getResim_list().get(position)));
new LoadImageTask(imageView).execute(MyGridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position));
```

Comment: You need to move the image loading into an AsyncTask - see edit

Comment: it requires android lvl 16 im using lvl 14

Comment: Change imageView.setBackground(drawable); to imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

Comment: i tried using .setImageDrawable on your .setBackground
didn't work

Comment: seem's like i need to redo this all over again using something else

Comment: I tested it and I got a GridView with pictures of pink and blue cartoon cats. There is probably something minor you need to fix. Uncomment the e.printStackTrace() call and check your LogCat to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! Nice job finding the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

are you set android.permission.INTERNET permission?

Comment: you need add permission, in your project file. it is AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: like this: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: i tried but still the same no images, i added 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.serverbase" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application .....>
<....>
i did it like that

Comment: really ? i test your code, when i add permission it can work. are you sure your image url ( http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/319/d/6/neko_chibi__s_by_alykun17-d32y2v5.jpg ) was valid ?